# What would cause nulls to be written to a text file?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-10

I have a large C# application that routinely writes small text files (max 3-4kb), as well as regularly appending to a daily log file.

Writing to the text files is done using `StreamWriter`, while the log file is written using NLog.

Occasionally (has been reported but I've only seen one example so far) one of the text files is found with just a long row of NULL characters (i.e. 0x00). The log file also contains (amongst its other valid data) a single record also with the NULL characters.

I don't have any code to write null characters to file, I'm just wondering what kind of phenomenon could cause this to happen?

My current suspicion is that a power loss occurred, or the OS (Windows 10) crashed at the time the file was being written. Maybe the OS had enough time to create the file and allocate the space for the data, but not to write the actual data into it. Furthermore, for the example I've seen, the next entries in the log file (an hour later) shows startup activity. Does this sound plausible? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Sounds plausible (hardware crash / "unplanned" os reboot). Not sure if there is some "recovering from system failure" flag somewhere that can be queried ... Alas, the Windows System Event Log should have something if the machine crashed ...

Comment: We need more details. It can be caused by many things. Can you trigger the script manually to test at different times. How about disk space on the server and permissions. Do you save the log in one file only or for every day a separate file? How about the naming of the files?